# What is the difference between credentials and certificates in an Azure Automation Account

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-powershell, azure-automation

Under the Automation Account section in Azure there seems to be two sections dedicated to  authentication. Credentials and Certificates, what are the different applications here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Automation credential asset holds a **PSCredential** object which contains security credentials such as a username and password.Runbooks and DSC configurations may use cmdlets that accept a PSCredential object for authentication, or they may extract the username and password of the PSCredential object to **provide to some application or service requiring authentication.** The properties for a credential are stored securely in Azure Automation and can be accessed in the runbook or DSC configuration with the `Get-AutomationPSCredential` activity.

An Automation Certificate assets store Certificates, so they can be accessed by runbooks or DSC configurations using the `Get-AzureRmAutomationCertificate` activity for Azure Resource Manager resources. **This allows you to create runbooks and DSC configurations that use certificates for authentication or adds them to Azure or third-party resources.**

More information about [Credential assets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-credentials) and [Certificate assets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-certificates), please refer to those links.

Comment: So they are both just different ways of handling credentials for authentication? What would the different use cases be?

Comment: yes, but authenticate for difference resources, credential authenticate for app or service, certificate allow you to create runbooks and DSC.